# How to transform gameObjects in array?

Tags: c#, arrays, transform, unity-game-engine

I have an array of available gameObjects in the scene. An array of GO should be transformed according to received floats through UDP connection. I know it is simple, but can't figure it out how to accomplish the transformation an array of GO according to received unique floats for each GO, any help will be appreciated.

Here is a transformation floats, it might be helpful I guess:

```
x =ReadSingleBigEndian(data, signalOffset);
        signalOffset+=4;
        y= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, signalOffset);
        signalOffset+=4;
        z= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, signalOffset);
        signalOffset+=4;
        alpha= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, signalOffset);
        signalOffset+=4;
        theta= ReadSingleBigEndian(data,signalOffset);
        signalOffset+=4;
        phi= ReadSingleBigEndian(data,signalOffset);
        signalOffset+=4;
```

Comment: Maybe ask this on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean translate the transform of the GameObjects? You can easily loop over your array of GameObjects to achieve that

```
public void translateEachGameObject(float x, float y, float z, GameObjects[] objects) {
   foreach(var obj in objects) {
      obj.transform.translate(x,y,z);
   }
}
```

[Transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.html) is an object within GameObject, and not a method in itself.

Comment: Yes, I meant transform of the GameObjects over the scene. My floats are unique for each GameObjects in array, in your answer x,y,z will be the same for all GameObjects.